# Skrollr: fading image jumping to top of z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I have some images scrolling normally with some overlaying div's creating a mask effect. 
It works fine but I want to fade-in the scrolling images. As soon as i add the opacity animation the fading image jumps to the top of the z-index stack until it hits opacity:1 & then it jumps back to its normal z-index.
Here is the [page in question](http://riquez.neocities.org/d4damage/index.html).

The 3 triangle shapes masking the images belong to the fixed positioned nav column which is outside #skrollr-body (as recommended)

```
<div class="tri6"></div>
<div class="tri7"></div>
<div class="tri8"></div>
```

& they are positioned over the right column where the scrolling images are.

```
<div class="page_photo" data-400="opacity: 0;" data-700="opacity: 1;">
<img src="photos/fight1.jpg">
<img src="photos/neutron4.jpg">
<img src="photos/indi.jpg">
<img src="photos/taxi.jpg">
<img src="photos/planet1.jpg">
</div>
```

I set the z-index of the image to -1 & the mask div's to 500, but that is not the solution. Not sure how to proceed - any advice?

to clarify: visit the linked site, scroll down. you will see a large image of a guy fighting. As that image scrolls 3 white triangles will appear. They should always be on top & not behind the animating opacity effect.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be having an effect. I edited the top-left triangle to position:relative & made it bright red so we can see clearly what is happening. The scrolling image that fades passes over the red triangle & then the red triangle jumps to the front once the fade is complete. http://riquez.neocities.org/d4damage/index.html

Comment: I think I've got it, posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it.  The problem is that the triangle's container does not have the z-index applied.

Try changing the style of col1 div to this:

```
.col1 {
float: left;
width: 20%;
min-width: 12em;
padding-top: 1em;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Let me know if that does the trick.

Comment: Very good. It doesn't completely solve the issue, but it is almost there. The z-indexing works to keep those triangles in front,  but it seems that the triangles also inherit the fade effect simply because they are over the top of the fade. Thank you. I think there were probably 2 issues here & you have solved one of them. :-)

Comment: Glad that solved one of the issues.  Do you not want the triangles to fade?  If you don't, you just need to change the data attributes like this

<div class="tri6" data-400="opacity: 1;" data-700="opacity: 1;"></div>

In order to make it stay opaque.

Comment: Perfect! Actually that fade is my fault totally. The tri6 data animations should not be there. I think I added it as part of troubleshooting - oOps! - so, your first answer was absolutely correct - thank you!